# Cursor does not display correctly when windows resize

Tags: c#, uwp

```xml
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveStates" CurrentStateChanged="AdaptiveStates_CurrentStateChanged">
     <VisualState x:Name="DefaultState">
           <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
           </VisualState.StateTriggers>
     </VisualState>

     <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
          <VisualState.StateTriggers>
               <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
          </VisualState.StateTriggers>
     </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Case 1: `Frame.GoBack();`

Case 2: `Frame.Navigate();`

Cursor does not display correctly when adaptive state changed
How to fix it?

[image: Cursor does not display correctly]

Comment: Are those `Case 1, Case 2` somehow connected with the problem?

Comment: This should be a bug report for Microsoft.  Just keeping your Win10 install updated is probably enough to get it fixed, eventually anyway.

Comment: It's an OS / platform bug, you can't fix it sadly.